# How to overwrite this function using a mixin?

Tags: javascript, jquery, magento, requirejs, magento2

I'm trying to override the function postcodeValidation inside of:

```
vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/js/model/shipping-rates-validator.js
```

I've been able to create a mixin, but i'm unsure how to alter the existing function. I'm wanting to change the validation message (without using CSV file).

This is the code in my mixin:

```
define(['mage/utils/wrapper', 'mage/translate', 'jquery'],function (wrapper, $t, $){
    'use strict';

    return function (target) {

        var postcodeValidation = wrapper.wrap(target.postcodeValidation, function(originalFunction, config, element){
            originalFunction();
            warnMessage = $t('test');
        });

        target.postcodeValidation = postcodeValidation;

        return target;
    };
});
```

Now this doesn't work, as warnMessage is undefined. Do I need to copy the whole function across?

Answer (score 2):

please try this:

```
define(['mage/utils/wrapper'], function (wrapper) {
'use strict';

return function (shippingRatesValidator) {
    shippingRatesValidator.postcodeValidation = wrapper.wrapSuper(shippingRatesValidator.postcodeValidation, function (postcodeElement) {
        this._super(postcodeElement);
        console.log('aaaaaaaaaaaaa');
        // add extended functionality here or modify method logic altogether
    });

    return shippingRatesValidator;
};});
```